# custom form - hide field based on other field value

Tags: jquery, html

i used next code in my custom form of document library

```
 `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript&quot;"></script><script type="text/javascript">`
```

`$(document).ready(function(){`
  `// col1 is hidden by default , col2 is visible`

`$('nobr:contains("Вођа тима - одобрење")').closest('tr').hide();`

`// Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection`

`// hide col2 and show col1 when selecting "dropdown option 1"`

`$("select[title='Обрађивач - одобрење']").change(function() {
  if ($("select[title='Обрађивач - одобрење]").val() == "Да") {
           $('nobr:contains("Вођа тима - одобрење")').closest('tr').show();
           $('nobr:contains("Врховни ревизор - одобрење")').closest('tr').show(); }`

`// hide col1 and show col2 when selecting "dropdown option 2"`

`else if($("select[title='Обрађивач - одобрење']").val() == "Не"){
         $('nobr:contains("Вођа тима - одобрење")').closest('tr').hide();
         $('nobr:contains("Врховни ревизор - одобрење")').closest('tr').hide();
      }
 });
});
 </script>`

my html tag of cutom form is like on picture
[image]

where is error?

Comment: would you mind organizing your code so we can read it better.  I know you are new, and that is cool :) but if you put 4 spaces before your entry when you post, it will put it in "code view".  Do this for each separate line to organize your code posting so it is easier for us to read.  We can help better that way

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are experiencing?  Does your initial hiding of "col1" work?  Have you put an `alert` or `console.log` inside your change handler to be sure that it is registering the change in drop down value?

Comment: Hiding of field is not working

Comment: sorry i edited  code based on my solution, but this code is not working

Comment: @Dylan Cristy i put alert in my code in  `else if($("select[title='Обрађивач - одобрење']").val() == "Не"){
         $('nobr:contains("Вођа тима - одобрење")').closest('tr').hide();
         $('nobr:contains("Врховни ревизор - одобрење")').closest('tr').hide();
      }` but my code does not give me alert

Comment: i delete &quot; from script tag <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript&quot;"> and part of code   $('nobr:contains("Вођа тима - одобрење")').closest('tr').hide();   is working.  $("select[title='Обрађивач - одобрење']").change(function() { ....   is not working, when select 'Да' i can not see other two fields